# Swappable trait interface

Tags: rust, polymorphism

I am trying a struct with a trait interface that I can change.
as in two structs `Circle` and `Square` that both implement the trait interface `Shape`
Then have a `Data` struct that holds a `Shape` that I can easily switch out for one or the other.

This I found achievable with `dyn Shape`, but I have a library function (that I can not change) that looks something like this:

```rust
fn lib_display_area<P>(p: P)
where
     P: Shape,
{
        println!("area is {}", p.area())
}
```

This does not like taking in a `dyn Shape` and gives me:

> the size for values of type `dyn Shape` cannot be known at compilation time
> the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Shape`

So instead I tried to implement my `Data` struct like this:

```rust
struct Data2<P>
where
P: Shape,
{
    shape: P
}
```

However, now I can no longer swap the `shape` variable to a different `Shape`.
Is there a way I can create a swappable `shape` variable that can also be sent to the lib function `lib_display_area`?

Full Example

```rust
trait Shape {
    fn area(&self) -> f32;
}

struct Circle{
    radius: f32,
}

impl Shape for Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.radius.powi(2) * std::f32::consts::PI
    }
}

struct Square {
    side: f32,
}

impl Shape for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.side.powi(2)
    }
}

struct Data1
{
    shape: Box<dyn Shape>
}

struct Data2<P>
where
P: Shape,
{
    shape: P
}

fn main() {
    let square = Square {side: 10.0};
    let circle = Circle {radius: 10.0};

    let data1 = Data1 { shape: Box::new(square) };
    
    lib_display_area(data1.shape.as_ref());// E0277


    
    let data = Data2 {shape: circle};
    lib_display_area(data.shape);
    data.shape = square; // E0308
    lib_display_area(data.shape);
}


fn lib_display_area<P>(p: P)
where
     P: Shape,
{
        println!("area is {}", p.area())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have to use `dyn` for this.

You can make this work, without changing `lib_display_area`, by using a wrapper struct that implements `Shape` and just delegates to the inner `&dyn Shape`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct DynShape<'a>(&'a dyn Shape);

impl<'a> Shape for DynShape<'a> {
    fn area(&self) -> f32 {
        self.0.area()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let square = Square {side: 10.0};
    let circle = Circle {radius: 10.0};

    let mut data1 = Data1 { shape: Box::new(square) };
    
    lib_display_area(DynShape(data1.shape.as_ref()));
    data1.shape = Box::new(circle);
    lib_display_area(DynShape(data1.shape.as_ref()));
}
```

---

Previous Answer

You can make `lib_display_area` work by taking a reference instead of taking shape by value:

```rust
fn lib_display_area<P: Shape + ?Sized>(p: &P) {
    println!("area is {}", p.area())
}
```

The `?Sized` bound just says "the type `P` can be unsized", which is necessary for `dyn Trait` trait objects. Even though the trait object itself is unsized, a reference to it is still sized, so we can pass it around.

```rust
fn main() {
    let square = Square { side: 10.0 };
    let circle = Circle { radius: 10.0 };

    let mut data1 = Data1 {
        shape: Box::new(square),
    };

    lib_display_area(data1.shape.as_ref());
    data1.shape = Box::new(circle);
    lib_display_area(data1.shape.as_ref());
}
```

Comment: That would be the way to go, if I was able to change the `lib_display_area` but it is an external library. So I am not able to. Thanks for the suggestion tho :D

Comment: If say `Shape` had a mutable function called `set_area(&mut self, area: f32)` and you wanted to implement for `DynShape`: `self.0.set_area(area)` rust then recommends me to change `DynShape` to `struct DynShape<'a>(&'a mut dyn Shape);` This means that I must `let mut data1 = Data1`. However in get `data1` as only a ref some places, where it is only calls the `lib_display_area`. So I get an error either with the `data1.shape.as_ref()` if the `DynShape`'s `Shape` is mutable or an error with `self.0.set_area(area)` if it is not. Don't know if you have a solution for this?

Comment: Note that if you own `Shape` you can `impl<T: Shape + ?Sized> Shape for &'_ T {}` and not use a wrapper struct.

Comment: @TomasBerger You can `panic!()` on `set_area()` (create a get-only wrapper). But this is fragile, I won't recommend umless you have to.